# how to get return value of exportsqlce (3rdparty exe to read sdf file in ssis)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-ce

Im using a 3rd party exe from Codeplex to read sql ce compact DB using Ssis.If it reads perticular Sdf file, it returns 0 and i'm using this return value for further processing.this is working fine.But, the problem comes, if this is not able to read SDF file. How do I know what is the failure return value? Thinking someone might have same problem, I am posting this.please help.

Answer (score 1):

The Exportsqlce code is Open Source, and can be seen here: https://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Program.cs (I am the author).
It will return 1 if an error occurs, and 2 if the command line is invalid.